# VSPackage menu item text doesn't update, Win8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vspackage

VS2013 Pro SP 4
Win 8.1 x64

I have two OleMenuCommands added to the Tools menu.   I have given them a handler for the BeforeQueryStatus event.

I have added debugging code to the OnBeforeQueryStatus() that shows the handler is being called, and the correct text is being selected.  However, the two menu items on the Tools menu are not correctly updated.  Here's OnBeforeQueryStatus():

```
private void OnBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
DbgMessage("OnBeforeQueryStatus");  
var myCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;  

if (null != myCommand)  
{  
    if (myCommand.CommandID.ID == (int)PkgCmdIdList.CmdIdCBAutoSave)  
    {  
        myCommand.Text = _autosaveEnabled ? "Disable Document AutoSave" : "Enable Document AutoSave";  
        DbgMessage(myCommand.Text);  
    }  
    if (myCommand.CommandID.ID == (int)PkgCmdIdList.CmdIdCBAutoSaveProject) 
    {  
        myCommand.Text = _autosaveProjectEnabled ? "Disable AutoSaveProject" : "Enable AutoSaveProject";  
        myCommand.Enabled = _autosaveEnabled;  
        DbgMessage(myCommand.Text);   
    }   
    DbgMessage(string.Format("Id: {0}  Text: {1}", myCommand.CommandID.ID, myCommand.Text));  
}  
}
```

In the .vsct file the `<Button>` elements have

```
<CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
```

How can I diagnose what is going wrong?  This doesn't seem to be an issue with the package installed in VS2012/2013 running on Win7.

Another strange observation:  When I debug the VSPackage (by starting devenv.exe with the /RootSuffix Exp argument), the menu items update as expected.

Comment: Here is the simplest example I could create that demonstrates the problem: http://1drv.ms/1xmZVYR

Answer (score 0):

Add `<CommandFlag>NoCache</CommandFlag>`

Comment: "Invalid token 'NoCache' given in a <CommandFlag> element of a <Button> element "